# How to display horizontally in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

There are two lines of out for every iteration of the loop. I want for line a to be on top of line b in every iteration. Moreover, I want to display the next (i=1) iterated line a and b to be horizontal with the previous (i=0) line a and b.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
     cout << "LOOP" << endl; //line a
     cout << i << endl;      //line b
}
```

Current output:

```
LOOP
0
LOOP
1
```

Desired output:

```
LOOP  LOOP
0     1
```

Comment: I would suggest making a loop for each line, and putting a `cout << endl;` between each loop.

Comment: `cout << "LOOP  LOOP\n0     1\n";` But more seriously, if you want to do fancy console output (like controlling where to print different lines of text) you'll need a library like ncurses. Native C++ doesn't give you any mechanism to control terminal text display.

Comment: You cannot do that with regular `cout`. There are two options: 1) buffer everything in memory in the required form and flush it to output once in a while, 2) use something like `ncurses` to arrange the output as you like

Comment: @OlivierGrech: This is a condensed version of over a hundred lines of code.

Comment: @JohnEscobia Note that if you have a single function with 100 lines of code, you should definitely refactor...

Comment: @Cornstalks thanks!

Comment: @hyde got it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the logic of your program as it is and store the output in a buffer before sending it to stdout.

For example you can use a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) for every line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::ostringstream line_a,
                       line_b;


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        line_a << std::setw(6) << "LOOP"; 
        line_b << std::setw(6) << i;  
    }

    std::cout << line_a.str() << '\n'
              << line_b.str() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    cout << "LOOP\t";
}

cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    cout << i << "\t";
}
```

Comment: This is a condensed version of over a hundred lines of code.

Comment: Do you what display the data as a table? how many columns there are?

Comment: The number of iteration depends on an input - which is another function. I guess I'll go along with buffer.

Comment: There will be always two rows and variable columns? if so, why you don't display it vertically? I think it's better for space

Comment: The number of iteration depends on the input, which could go up to 25 or more.